# Can I see the total amount of my crafting materials?

Tags: diablo-iii

The game seems to display "*" when the amount of material exceeds 999 in the blacksmith's crafting menu. I don't have any estimate for the amount of arcane dust I have (on the middle; I've always mainly disenhanced magical items).

Are the crafting materials also listed elsewhere and in full?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you click on the little anvil icon at the bottom of your inventory window, it will open up a new window with all your materials in it, and you can see how many of each you have:

[image]

[image]